# Модель "Клиент" с ссылкой "партнер" на экземпляр своего класса. Как обработать событие присваивания ссылки?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Пишу чат-рулетку на RoR, создал таблицу Clients с полем partner_id.
Код модели:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :partner, :class_name => 'Client'
  has_one    :partner, :class_name => 'Client', :foreign_key => 'partner_id'
end
```

Как сделать, что бы при присваивании `client.partner = other_client` клиенты обменивались ссылками, а не просто она присваивалась одному? Я так понимаю события удаления обрабатывать `before_destroy`, что бы очищать `partner_id` у партнера?

Есть ли другие пути создания таких зависимостей?

Comment: У вас две связи belongs_to и has_one называются одинаково :partner - лучше так не делать.

Comment: Я так понимаю в таком случае одна из связей должна называться inverse_partner?

Comment: Да, лучше переименовать, иначе глюки вам обеспечены.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inverse_partner, :class_name => 'Client', :foreign_key => 'partner_id'
  has_one    :partner, :class_name => 'Client', :foreign_key => 'partner_id'

  before_destroy :unsubscribe_partner

  def partner=(client)
    existing_partner = self.partner

    puts ">>>> BEFORE".red
    log ">>>> SELF:", self
    log ">>>> SELF.PARTNER:", existing_partner if existing_partner
    log ">>>> CLIENT:", client

    raise ArgumentError.new("Partner can't be self") if client == self

    super

    puts ">>>> AFTER SUPER".red
    log ">>>> SELF:", self
    log ">>>> SELF.PARTNER:", existing_partner if existing_partner
    log ">>>> CLIENT:", client

    self.partner_id = client.id

    puts ">>>> AT END".red
    log ">>>> SELF:", self
    log ">>>> SELF.PARTNER:", existing_partner if existing_partner
    log ">>>> CLIENT:", client
  end

  private
  def unsubscribe_partner
    self.partner_id = nil
  end

  def log (prompt, table)
    print prompt
    print "id = ", "#{table.id}".red, ", "
    print "partner_id = ", "#{table.partner_id}".red, "\n"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, перегрузите метод `partner=`

```
def partner=(client)
  super
  # TODO: выдать исключение, если client == self
  client.partner_id = self.id
  client.save
end
```

Comment: Я не совсем понял, но нужно писать `self.partner_id = client.id` вместо `client.partner_id = self.id`, я так понимаю, это из-за того, что `partner=` вызывается для присваиваемого значения